# QuickBlox login with Facebook's own SDK?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, quickblox

Is it possible to use QuickBlox iOS SDK in conjunction with Facebook's iOS SDK to log into service?

Or rather, my real intention is to be able to to use Facebook to find the user's liked page. So I need to create Facebook session. Anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method 'Login with Facebook access token'

```
 [QBUsers logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" accessToken:@"AAAGmLYiu1lcBADxROiXg4okE80FQO1dJHglsbNT63amxmABnmBmhN6ACbgD7qNC3H4Y9GmZAdoSfPUkI9O7ZBJvKQCewNZAp3SoxKCNIMwQZDZD" accessTokenSecret:nil delegate:self];
```

In this case you need to use Facebook SDK to obtain access token.

Answer (score 2):

You can login via Facebook or Twitter. More details there http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Sign_In_.26_Social_authorization
In this case QB-user will contain facebookID field.

For creating facebook session you need use facebook sdk. Quickblox doesn't support it. 
You can only mix this SDKs to achieving your purposes.